# Finding density of polar coordinate $R$ given uniformly distributed square

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

Given a square with side length 2 centered on (0,0) and with uniform distribution of X and Y, I want to find the density of $R$ with polar coordinates $R,\theta$.

I know that $f(x,y)$ over the area is $1/4$, that X and Y are independent, and that in polar coordinates we have $R=\sqrt{X^2 + Y^2}$ and $\theta = \arctan(Y/X)$. Using this, how do I find the marginal density of $R$?

Comment: This density is one of several illustrated on the graph at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/317484/2958 - it is the one that rises linearly to a peak at $1$ and then falls rapidly (it makes no difference whether you have a unit square with a vertex at the origin or a square sized $2$ centred at the origin)

Comment: Thank you, this helps illustrate, but I am interested in solving the problem analytically for an explicit expression of R.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly there is zero probability for $R \lt 0$ and $R \gt \sqrt 2$

The density for $R$ is proportional to the circumference of the circle centred at $(0,0)$ of radius $r$ which lies within the square.

Geometrically, this circumference is $2\pi r$ when $0 \le r \le 1$ and $2\pi r - 8 r \cos^{-1} \left(\tfrac1r\right)$  when $1 \le r \le \sqrt{2}$.

The constant of proportionality is the area of the square which is $4$; you could work it out analytically including using $\int\limits_1^{\sqrt{2}} 8 r \cos^{-1} \left(\tfrac1r\right) \, dr = \left. 4r^2 \cos^{-1} \left(\tfrac1r\right)  - 4r \sqrt{1-\tfrac1{r^2}}\right|_1^{\sqrt{2}} = 2\pi -4$.

So the density for $R$ is $\frac{\pi}2 r$ when $0 \le r \le 1$ and is $\frac{\pi}2r - 2 r \cos^{-1} \left(\tfrac1r\right)$  when $1 \le r \le \sqrt{2}$.

It looks something like

[image]